# Facebook: Getting name of the members

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to name of the members of close friends list:

```
FB.api("/me/friendlists/close_friends?fields=members.fields(name)")
```

but it is not working.

FB.api("/me/friendlists/close_friends?fields=members")

gives me complete members object with following structure

```
Object {data: Array[1], paging: Object}
data: Array[1]
0: Object
id: "10150338266588525"
members: Object
data: Array[1]
0: Object
id: "812290716"
name: "My Friend"
```

Comment: That path works for me. In fact, `/me/friendlists/close_friends?fields=members` returns the same result.

Comment: What about getting just the names of close_friends?

Comment: The Graph API likes to return an id with everything. I don't think you can suppress this unless you use FQL: `SELECT name FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid FROM friendlist_member WHERE flid IN (SELECT flid FROM friendlist WHERE owner = me() AND type = 'close_friends'))`

Answer (score 1):

To read a FriendList, issue an HTTP GET request to /FRIENDLIST_ID with
the read_friendlists permission.

```
FB.api("/FRIENDLIST_ID?fields=name,members.fields(name)")
```

You can also call like this, this returns name and id ( default), just ignore the userid, if you dont want.

```
FB.api("friendlists/close_friends?fields=members.fields(name)")
```

Try FB [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), Hope this helps.